# HTML canvas events on overlapping objects?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I have a canvas with a circle that changes color upon clicking on it, I can use a click event on the canvas element and handle the math for that (distance formula calculation <= radius).  But what if I have two circles that overlap (like a van diagram), and I click in the middle of the two circles assuming that only the top circle should change color?  If the math of the first circle is applied in this case, both circles would change color.

How would I deal with events in the canvas in terms of overlapping objects like the example above?  With hopefully a fast/efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want a framework like EaselJS that has a better api for what you're trying to do. Barebones canvas 2d-context doesn't provide much in terms of display-object / sprite behavior.

Responses above also mention some sort of list to represent layers. I don't think the implementation would be very difficult, just another condition to check for along with the radius.

Comment: i think it is a good idea to go with a javascript library, think i'll try kinetic.js

Answer (score 1):

Canvas isn't really like Flash or like a DOM tree whereby things have sort orders or z-indexes. Its a bit more like a flat rastered image and you have to rely upon other logic in your javascript to remember the sequence & stacking order of things you have drawn.

If you need this kind of interactivity I've always found it best to use a 3rd party library (unless it really is just a case of one or two circles which dont do much).

For interactive 'shape' based javascript graphics I would sugest Raphael.js or D3 which are actually more of SVG tools than a canvas one so maybe it's not for you but they are simple and cross-browser.

There's also processing.js (js port of Processing the Java lib) which feels a bit like flash and again can track all of the levels and objects. Theres a tonne of others but thats another topic.

If it's super simple the options might be:

1. Hold the co-ordinates of all shapes/elements composited on the canvas inside an object or array which also tracks their z-index/sort sequence, thereby letting you know whats on top.
2. Using the imagedata at the mouse coordinate of the click to establish what has been clicked
3. using multiple canvases composited on each other and letting the DOM do the work for the click events